# Select query taking time in Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-performance, oracle12c

I have the below query in my production environment

```
SELECT CIF,
  DECODE( 'INFENG' , '' ,NVL(ALT1_NAME,NAME),NAME),
  DECODE( 'INFENG' , '' ,NVL(ALT1_SHORT_NAME,SHORT_NAME),SHORT_NAME),
  CORP_ID
FROM tb.CMG ,
  tb.SST
WHERE SST.BANK_ID      = '54'
AND CMG.PRIMARY_SOL_ID = SST.SOL_ID
AND SST.SET_ID         = '000'
AND CMG.BANK_ID        = '54'
AND CMG.ENTITY_CRE_FLG = 'Y'
AND EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM tb.CPHONE
  WHERE CPHONE.PHONE_B2KID = CMG.CIF_ID
  AND PHONENO LIKE '%4444%'
  )
AND CORP_ID IS NULL
AND ROWNUM   < 801
ORDER BY 4
```

It is taking more than 5 minutes to give the result. The explain plan for the query is

```
  Plan hash value: 4143484456

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                          |     1 |   207 |  9732   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                          |                          |     1 |   207 |  9732   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY                         |                          |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    FILTER                               |                          |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                        |                          |  4325 |   874K|  5297   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                       |                          | 44112 |   874K|  5297   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IDX_SOL_ID_SET_TABLE     |     1 |    16 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IX_ACCOUNTS_PSOLID       | 44112 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | ACCOUNTS                 |  4325 |   806K|  5296   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |     NESTED LOOPS SEMI NA                |                          |     1 |    92 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| PHONEEMAIL               |     1 |    83 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IX_ORGKEY_PHONEEMAILTYPE |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| NON_CUSTOMERS            |     1 |     9 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | PK322                    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(ROWNUM<801)
   3 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT /*+ <not feasible>)
   6 - access("SST"."SET_ID"='000' AND "SST"."BANK_ID"='54')
       filter("SST"."BANK_ID"='54')
   7 - access("ACCOUNTS"."PRIMARY_SOL_ID"=SYS_OP_C2C("SOL_ID") AND "ACCOUNTS"."BANK_ID"=U'54')
   8 - filter("ACCOUNTS"."ENTITY_CRE_FLAG"=U'Y' AND "ACCOUNTS"."CORP_ID" IS NULL)
  10 - filter("PHONEEMAIL"."PHONEOREMAIL"=U'PHONE' AND SUBSTR("PHONENO",1,20) LIKE U'%4444%' AND 
              SUBSTR("PHONENO",1,20) IS NOT NULL AND "SUSPECTID" IS NULL AND "CONTACTID" IS NULL)
  11 - access("PHONEEMAIL"."ORGKEY"=:B1)
  12 - filter("A"."CONVFLAG"=U'N' OR "A"."CONVFLAG" IS NULL)
  13 - access("A"."NONCUSTOMERID"="PHONEEMAIL"."NONCUSTOMERID")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=1)
   - this is an adaptive plan
   - 1 Sql Plan Directive used for this statement
```

Could someone tell me how to optimize this query to reduce the execution time.

I have the same date in test database where the query is taking less than a minute. The explain plan there is

```
   Plan hash value: 888087711

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                      |     1 |   296 | 15491   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT UNIQUE                            |                      |     1 |   296 | 15490   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY                         |                      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                         |                      |     1 |   296 | 15489   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                        |                      |     1 |   283 | 15488   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI NA            |                      |     1 |    92 | 15487   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL         | NON_CUSTOMERS        |     9 |    81 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |       TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL         | PHONEEMAIL           |   783K|    62M| 15482   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| ACCOUNTS             |     1 |   191 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IX_ACCOUNTS_ORGKEY   |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | IDX_SOL_ID_SET_TABLE |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(ROWNUM<801)
   5 - access("A"."NONCUSTOMERID"="PHONEEMAIL"."NONCUSTOMERID")
   6 - storage("A"."CONVFLAG"=U'N' OR "A"."CONVFLAG" IS NULL)
       filter("A"."CONVFLAG"=U'N' OR "A"."CONVFLAG" IS NULL)
   7 - storage("PHONEEMAIL"."PHONEOREMAIL"=U'PHONE')
       filter("PHONEEMAIL"."PHONEOREMAIL"=U'PHONE' AND SUBSTR("PHONENO",1,20) LIKE U'%4444%' AND 
              SUBSTR("PHONENO",1,20) IS NOT NULL AND "SUSPECTID" IS NULL AND "CONTACTID" IS NULL)
   8 - filter("ACCOUNTS"."ENTITY_CRE_FLAG"=U'Y' AND "ACCOUNTS"."CORP_ID" IS NULL)
   9 - access("PHONEEMAIL"."ORGKEY"="ACCOUNTS"."ORGKEY" AND "ACCOUNTS"."BANK_ID"=U'54')
  10 - access("SST"."SET_ID"='000' AND "SST"."BANK_ID"='54')
       filter("SST"."BANK_ID"='54' AND "ACCOUNTS"."PRIMARY_SOL_ID"=SYS_OP_C2C("SST"."SOL_ID"))

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=1)
   - this is an adaptive plan
   - 2 Sql Plan Directives used for this statement
```

Comment: This this would be better for dba exchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the datatype for columns `CMG.PRIMARY_SOL_ID` and `SST.SOL_ID`. Hope one of them is `NVARCHAR()`, resulting with implicit conversion call `SYS_OP_C2C()`, suppressing the usage of index.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar cmg.primary_sol_id is NVARCHAR2 and sst.sol_id is VARCHAR2

Comment: Great, so that's the culprit probably, you might want to add a function based index over that column like `to_nchar(CMG.PRIMARY_SOL_ID)`. Or match the datatypes of those columns. [More details here](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/07/29/nls/)

Comment: Please note that in your explain plan the `count stopkey` comes first followed by the `sort order by`. Because Oracle doesn't guarantee order in tables this means you're selecting 800 random rows then ordering them, which is _usually_ the opposite of people's intentions.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar I'll try to do that.. I have edited the que because the same query in a different database is taking much lesser time

Comment: The Explain Plan shows total execution time (estimated) of one second. What's up with that? Can you generate an actual EXECUTION plan and share? Then - if the optimizer thinks it will do everything in one second, it is possible that your statistics are stale. Are they? And, why does the Explain Plan show the SELECT statement will return only one row and not 800? **OR**... Is that plan **NOT REALLY** from the query you posted? Too many things seem different.

Comment: First of all, get rid of all literals like '000','54', 'Y','%4444%',801 to prevent hard parsing of SQL statements.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan for queries taking minutes to execute is hard parsing not only negligible, but it can provide vital cardinality information for the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

You provide no much information (for exaple you didn't say if the query returns the full 800 row or less), so an exact answer is not possible.

Here are some steps you should follow to troubleshoot the statement:

**1. Understand what the query is doing**

The query is joining two tables `CMG` and `SST`. Additionaly it performs  `EXISTS` subquery from  `CMG` to `CPHOME`
(which is probable a view of two tables).
Finally you limit the result to 800 rows.

**2. Find an acceptable execution plan**

You should convince yourself which execution plan is *correct* - som ebasic knowled about your data is required for it.

The obvious starting point is the table `CMG` (becouse it is involved in both the join and the EXISTS subquery).

The question is what to do next - the join or the EXISTS condition. Your fist execution plan performs first the join and than resolves the EXISTS (`NESTED LOOPS SEMI`).
The long excution time suggest that it is not OK. One explanation would be that the EXISTS is very restrictive, i.e. not much  `CPHONE`s exists for a  `CMG`. 
So you performs a lot of join loops to the SST table only to through them away because no `CPHONE` exists.

The second execution plan supports this theory as it first performs the EXISTS predicate (using `HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI`) and than the join.

**3. Bring Oracle to perform that excution plan**

So why is Oracle not doing a "right" job? Shelves of books are written about it - here only the very basic and obvious things:

- you use in both environments `dynamic sampling level 1`, it means that at least one table has no optimizer statistics at all **and** you use only 32 block for dynamic sampling.

Either collect the missing statistics or alternatively increase the DS level (you may do it with a hint in the query).

- Note that you use in both environment Sql Plan Directives and you have two of them in test and only one in prod. Check them what part of the wrong estimation they try to correct.
- run the query with [`dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sqltun.htm#ARPLS220)    to see the difference between the estimated cardinality and the 
  *actual* cardinality.